# Is there a way to avoid reheating of steel billets in Reheat furnace and directly go from casting to roll milling?

Tags: steel, manufacturing-engineering, casting

Iron ore and few compounds added will result in steel which are casted to steel billers form. this billet is again reheated to melting point of 1200c and then sent to roughing mill for desired shape. can we avoid reheat furnance and directly cast and then roughing mill?

Comment: I read somewhere that this direct procedure is called hot connect. But I did not find any google results for this. Anybody know it?

Comment: Why would they spend the money on a reheat furnace (not cheap) if it was not necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Historically production was : ingot > reheat> bloom > reheat > billet. For about the last 40 years production has been  : continuous casting directly produces billets. An ingot was roughly 2 ' X 4' X  8 ' . Continuous strands can be down to about 6 " X very long. There are a great number of variations depending on final product , alloy, the individual mill , etc. A billet form is inventoried until needed , then heated and shaped. The homogenization and grain refinement provided by reheat also need to be considered.